# How to implement SQLITE_LIMIT_LENGTH?

Tags: android, sqlite, react-native

I am using `SQLite` in my RN apps with help of `react-native-sqlite-storage`. Then, one of my table has a column which contain a very long `string`. When I try to `insert` the `string`, no error occured. But, when I `select` the row, it return `null`. This [open issue](https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage/issues/271) is similar with my problem.

Then, I found this [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html). It said that

> During part of SQLite's INSERT and SELECT processing, the complete
>   content of each row in the database is encoded as a single BLOB. So
>   the SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH parameter also determines the maximum number of
>   bytes in a row.
>
> The maximum string or BLOB length can be lowered at run-time using the
>   sqlite3_limit(db,SQLITE_LIMIT_LENGTH,size) interface.

My question is, if I have this piece of working code to `select` data from a table:

```
const db = await SQLite.openDatabase('databasename', 'default');
db.executeSql('SELECT * FROM tablename', [], (res) => {
  console.log(res.rows.item(0));
}, err => console.log(err));
```

How to implement `sqlite3_limit(db, SQLITE_LIMIT_LENGTH, size)` to above code in order to increase the `SQLITE_LIMIT_LENGTH`?

Comment: A quick glance at the readme for react-native-sqlite-storage suggests it doesn't provide an interface to `sqlite3_limit()`. Unfortunately, many language's sqlite bindings only export a fraction of the C API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't easily.  Android's default sqlite implementation doesn't provide access to it.  You would need to import your own version of the sqlite Java library (which is really a C library accessed via JNI), then provide your own RN module to access it in Java, then use only that module to access the db at all.  Its a lot of work.  How large is this string?  You may want to consider storing it in a file and putting the filename in the db.

The issue you linked particularly mentioned images.  Sqlite is not really a good solution for storing images, for a variety of reasons.  Use a file and store the filename for that.